# Kohana 3: getting related data from an ORM model

Tags: php, orm, kohana

When using Kohana 3's ORM models, what is the best way to get data from fields of related models? For example, I have an employee, who has one company, and has many assignments. How would I go about getting data from fields in the company model and assignment model(s) (i.e. in a has_one and a has_many relationship)?

EDIT: as requested, here are the models in question.

**User Model**

```
class Model_User extends ORM {
    protected $_table_name = 'user';
    protected $_primary_key = 'id';
    protected $_primary_val = 'username';
    protected $_has_many = array(
        'task' => array(
            'model' => 'task',
            'foreign_key' => 'user',
        ),
    );
    protected $_belongs_to = array(
        'company' => array(
            'model' => 'company',
            'foreign_key' => 'company'
        ),
    );
```

**Task Model**

```
class Model_Task extends ORM {
    protected $_table_name = 'tasks';
    protected $_primary_key = 'id';
    protected $_primary_val = 'name';
    protected $_belongs_to = array(
        'project' => array(
            'model' => 'project',
            'foreign_key' => 'project'
        ),
        'user' => array(
            'model' => 'user',
            'foreign_key' => 'user'
        ),
    );
```

**Company Model**

```
class Model_Company extends ORM {
    protected $_table_name = 'companies';
    protected $_primary_key = 'id';
    protected $_primary_val = 'name';
    protected $_has_many = array(
        'user' => array(
            'model' => 'user',
            'foreign_key' => 'company'
        ),
    );

}
```

**Code Throwing Error, From Controller**

```
$users = ORM::factory('user')->find_all();
$list = array();
foreach($users as $user) {
   $list[$user->id] = array(
     'username' => $user->username,
     'email' => $user->email,
     'company' => $user->company->name  //error:Trying to get property of non-object
   )
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Use plural forms for multiple relationships (has_many). Company has many *users*, user has many *tasks* etc. Its not critical but recommended.
2. What is the column name for company in the `users` table? Seems like its a `company` instead of `company_id`. If so, you can rename this foreign key or relation name.

Comment: Ah, I see it: 'foreign_key' => 'company' in Model_User. You cant use both foreign key and relation with the same names.

Answer (score 0):

To get the company you would do

```
$employee->company
```

So you can get the company properties with

```
$employee->company->property
```

To get the assignments you would do

```
$employee->company->assignments->find_all();
```

You can also chain other query methods such as ->where() before you call find_all() or find().

Comment: I tried this, but company was the ID of the company, not the company itself. Is there anything I need to do when constructing the employee model to get the related models to populate?

Comment: @GSto, can you add your Kohana models to your post?

Answer (score 0):

Well, if your employee can only belong to one company then to access the company would be done like so:

```
$company = $employee->company;
```

You can then access `$company` properties (fields) like you would with any other model.

I believe there's no limit to the depth of relations you can access, so doing

```
$assignments $employee->company->assignments->find_all();
```

is possible. Make note of the `find_all();` where you expect to have more than one record returned.